# Hdd never spins down in Debian or Ubuntu

Tags: hard-drive, samba, debian, rsyslog

I am currently using Debian because I have an old computer. I am running xfce4 as DKE. I only want to use it as a print server, nothing else but the hdd keeps running hot to 59Celsius and its not doing anything. I have added noatime to fstab and used iotop to try to find other things to disable. I even disabled rsyslog because it was constantly writing to the disk. (like 1gb/hour). It seem syslog is still needed for samba to work so i guess I need it in the future but I can't find any way to make the hdd stop and cool down. What am I missing? I have reinstalled to ubuntu and debian back and fort 6-7 times now because I thought maybe that would help but nothing. 
Smart is also enabled on the hdd btw. Please help me!

Edit1: I realised I didn't need the rsyslog (printer still working) so I deactivated it, I have also run some he-arm attributes and cleared logs. Turns out the Daemon.log and syslog were huge so I made log rotate and now I have basically eliminated the disk write. But I CANNOT get the hdd to stop spinning. The journaling jdbd2/sda1-8 is constantly active (about 2% IO when I look in iotop) but no logs are growing so it's no writing anything to the disk. I think this is the key to the spinning.

Comment: You could try hdparm with -B and -S options (man hdparm for more info).  I don't think it's going to help without solving the rsyslog problem first.

Comment: Ok thanks. But how do I go about to solve the syslog issue? What is the reason for it to act that way? Btw APM_level = 127 when typing hdparm. -S says "bad/missing standby-interval value...